# Toggle between 2 cameras, 2 person to very close up

Tags: video-recording

We have been making video's while talking in 2 chairs.  No one monitors the camera (we don't have a 3rd person)  We'd like to have another camera which could be switched to for close ups of what we are talking about. We have a Canon Power Shot, various Iphones and a Logitech video camera as well as a few tripods.

I don't know how to edit videos and really don't have the time to learn or I could slip a photo into the videos.  That's not what we would like to do. But while I have you, eventually I'm going to need to get into editing the video's cause the door bell is going to ring or something is going to happen, there's no pause button. What's the easiest program for doing this? Or is there a tool which will also pause the recording?

Is there a tool we can purchase to toggle between cameras? I found something that will hold the Iphone on the tripod as well as a blue tooth on off switch for the camera.

This is the final thing we need to churn out videos.  I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's common to set up one master shot, and 2 over-the-shoulder cameras (each one looking at one person's face with the back of the other person's shoulder somewhat in the shot).  These would be 3 separate cameras, all running simultaneously.

I have used Adobe Premiere CC (CC means "Creative Cloud") to edit this kind of a setup.  You can import the footage from all 3 camera angles, sync up the sound between the 3 tracks, and then toggle from camera to camera in real time!  For example:

- You shoot a 10-minute conversation with 3 cameras.
- You import the three 10-minute tracks into Adobe Premiere CC.
- You align them so they are all synchronized.
- You play them back and, while they are playing, you can click on the track that you want to see at that moment.  In effect, it will be "cutting" from camera to camera.  That will take you 10 minutes (because you're doing it in real-time).
- You export that footage as another video file.  It will show the conversation and will include all of the "cuts" (switching of camera angles) that you did while it was playing in Premiere.

I recommend using the sound from only ONE of the cameras.  You can mute the other 2 cameras.

FYI, there are probably other editing software programs that can do exactly this.  Adobe Premiere CC is just the one I've used.  I like its interface, and instead of paying a large amount of money up front, you pay a small amount per month.

Comment: WOW your so far beyond where we are.  I get what you are saying but this is more like a movie type of thing.  So is there no such creature as some sort of toggle switch?  The 2nd camera needs to be off while we are talking and then we'd switch to the close up of a small item on a table... very close details.  I've found the magnifying cameras but it's useless if I don't have the toggle.  I know of 2 people who do this. I guess it's time to find their contact information. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'll bet there is a consumer version of a "video switchboard" that would toggle between cameras like you're talking about. They use those for live new broadcasts. The way I envision it is that all the cameras would feed into the switchboard, and there would be one output that would go to a recorder (or a built-in recorder). As you "toggle", the input from the camera you selected would start being recorded. I've never done this, and I've found I can get the same effect by doing it AFTER I've shot, using an cheap editing program. (Sorry I made it sound so complicated! It's really simple.)